# Translate C++ Constructor into Java

Tags: java, c++, porting

I'm working on translating a small package from C++ to Java. I've never really used C++, so some of the syntax is a bit of a mystery. In particular, I'm having difficulty working out what the Java equivalent to this would be:

```
file: SomeClass.cpp

SomeClass::SomeClass( BitStream* data, const char* const filename ) :
    data( data ), cipher( filename ), iv( new Botan::byte [cipher.BLOCK_SIZE] ),
    ivBitsSet( 0 ), keyMaterialRemaining( 0 ), keyMaterial( new Botan::byte [cipher.BLOCK_SIZE] ) {}
```

I'm happy with (in Java):

```
public SomeClass{
  public SomeClass(InputStream data, String filename){

  }
}
```

but I'm not sure what to do with the stuff after the `:` in the C++. Are they fields? Optional parameters? Apologies for trivial question, but haven't got far with Google on this...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Everything after ":" is called the member initialization list, in C++ this is one way of initialising the members of this class. For example from your code, "data" is a member of SomeClass, so the equivalent in Java would be a simple assignment in the body of the constructor.

```
this.data = data;
```

etc. for all the other members

Answer (score 4):

Those are [field initializer lists](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html). They set the initial values for the fields.

The Java-Version is something like

```
public SomeClass{
  public SomeClass(InputStream data, String filename){
    //either set the field directly...
    this.data = data;
    //...or call the constructor, depending on the type
    this.cipher = new Cipher(filename);
  }
}
```

Note that this are not necessarily simple field setters, they may also be calls to the field type's constructor.

Answer (score 2):

cipher(filename) is equivalent to writing cipher = filename;

Comment: Not so. But cipher=filename is as close as Java can get to what cipher(filename) does.

Answer (score 1):

This simply is the C++ way to initialize all the class members.